# mysql insert command with a where clause

Tags: mysql, insert, where-clause

im trying to insert data into a particular row in the database, but i mysql is saying this is an error:

```
INSERT INTO user (rep, course) VALUES('5', 'computer science') WHERE user='2'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
UPDATE user 
   SET rep = '5', course = 'computer science' 
 WHERE user = '2'
```

[Link to docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html).

Answer (score 2):

You might want to [UPDATE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Update_%28SQL%29) instead,

```
UPDATE user set rep='5', course='computer science' WHERE user='2'
```

Comment: oh my god, i am so stupid, i totally forgot about update, thank god my db admin is not on stackoverflow ::))) cheers nos

Answer (score 1):

INSERT statement should not come with WHERE clause.

Answer (score 0):

`INSERT` statement can not be used with `WHERE` clause because you are going to insert a new row using `INSERT` so how could you check any condition over the row which even doesn't exits ?

That's the main reason you can't use `WHERE` clause with `INSERT` statement....

use: `UPDATE table-name SET column=val WHERE some cont`

Command if you need to update existing row....